# Don't put the current value in the form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Faced such a problem that the current values ​​about the user are not passed to the form. What I want to do is to combine the user model and the profile model, then display the current user data in two forms for editing. It seems to be done correctly, but for some reason it does not work. Please tell me who understands this)

file `views.py`:

```
class ProfilePage(UpdateView):
        model=Profile
        template_name="market/profile.html"
        form_class=ProfileUpdateForm
        second_model = User
        second_form_class= UserUpdateForm
    
    
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(ProfilePage,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['UserUpdateForm'] = UserUpdateForm(
                prefix='UserUpdateForm', 
                data = self.request.POST,
                instance=self.request.user,
            )
            context['ProfileUpdateForm'] = ProfileUpdateForm(
                prefix='ProfileUpdateForm', 
                data = self.request.POST,
                files = self.request.FILES,
                instance=self.request.user.profile,
            )
            return context
    
        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            super(ProfilePage,self).post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
            context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
            if context['UserUpdateForm'].is_valid():
                context['UserUpdateForm'].save()
            elif context['ProfileUpdateForm'].is_valid():
                context['ProfileUpdateForm'].save()
            return self.render_to_response(context)
```

file `forms.py`:

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username",)


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Profile
        fields=('valuta','slug','avtor')
```

file `models.py`:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avtor=models.ImageField(default='user_images/default.jpg', upload_to='user_images',blank=True)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True,blank=True)
    valuta=models.ForeignKey(Valuta,default="5", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

file `profile.html`:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{UserUpdateForm.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ProfileUpdateForm.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: When you say `current values ​​about the user are not passed to the form` do you mean when the form is initialized, the form fields aren't prefilled with the User object values? Or do you mean when POSTing?

Comment: when the page is loaded and it issues this https://ibb.co/BfYwbzk, 
I want the form to contain the current data about the user, there is his username

Comment: Is the template just doing {{ form }}? You can declare `initial` as a kwarg in the init function of the form if you need to. Let me know if you don't know what I mean and I'll write an answer

Comment: Yes, I think this is what I need. I need the user to see their data immediately. And I updated the question by adding template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your forms in your `get_context_data`, you also pass `self.request.POST`. So it tries to render the form with the POST data (whereas it is empty at first).

You should add `or None` for this line for UserUpdateForm and ProfileUpdateForm :

```
data = self.request.POST or None,
```

And also for the ProfileUpdateForm where it uses `files` :

```
files = self.request.FILES or None,
```

Then it will render the form with the instance data and use POST data when it exists.

Comment: When I click submit, the form is saved, everything is correct, but now another problem has appeared - the page is loaded, where another form is empty and with an error :(

Comment: I believe this is because you separated in two forms in your HTML. When you submit, only one form is being passed through your request, thus the other form doesn't have required data when loaded then.

Comment: It's sad, because when I have forms together, then there is also a bug, when I save the form, I get an error in the login field - "this user already exists." Okay, thanks anyway