# How can I delete a record from the database through a template?

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I delete a record from the database through a template? For example, I have a list of comments that I received from the database and displayed on the page, next to them there is an icon with a basket and when I click on the icon, the entry should be deleted from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your delete buttons (or inputs) may be inside forms, because you may want to delete with POST, avoiding the default behavior of the Generic DeleteView (GET renders a confirmation page and it's not good UX). I suppose you're doing a for loop:

Template:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
...
<form method="POST" id="{{object.pk}}"  action="/delete_url/{{object.pk}}/" ...> {%csrf_token%}
    <button class="your-class" id="{{object.pk}}" method="submit" ...>
</form>
...
{% endfor %}
```

Define the url path in your urls.py:

```
from your_path.views import MyDeleteView
...
path("/delete_url/<pk>/", MyDeleteView.as_view()),
```

Now you should define your delete view. The simplest way is inheriting the DeleteView from generics view:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView 
from your_path.models import MyModel

class MyDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = MyModel
    sucess_url = "/home/"
```

And for delete confirmation you can use javascript. That's an example I used, feel free to adapt:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".your-class").click(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            e.preventDefault();. //prevent instant submit
            Swal.fire({
                  title: 'Deseja deletar este usuário? Esta ação não poderá ser desfeita.',
                  buttonsStyling: false,
                  confirmButtonText: "<i class='la la-trash'></i> Deletar",
                  customClass: {
                      confirmButton: "btn btn-danger",
                      cancelButton: "btn btn-default"
                  },
                  showCancelButton: true,
                  cancelButtonText: `Cancelar`,
                  icon: "warning",
            }).then((result) => {
                  if (result.isConfirmed) {
                 Swal.fire({
                      title: 'Deletando colaborador...',
                      timer: 1000,
                      showCancelButton: false,
                      showConfirmButton: false
                  });

                  var id = $(this).attr('id');
                  setTimeout(function() {
                      $('form#'+id).submit();
                   }, 1000); // 1 second delay
             }
             // else if (result.isDenied) {
             //   Swal.fire('Changes are not saved', '', 'info');
             //   e.preventDefault();
             // }
      });
    });
});
</script>
```

If you just want the simplest GET render confirmation page without any javascript, remove the form tag and use the anchor one (<a href=/delete_url/{{object.pk}}/"> ... )

Comment: Can I somehow do this without the DeleteView?I just inherit everything from UpdateView

Comment: I have a profile and I am changing it. I also have a model with comments, so I need to somehow delete records in this model

Comment: Not sure if I understood. What view renders your template? What are your models? How are they connected? Are you updating a profile, which is a instance of a model (maybe Profile or User), and just need to delete some linked comments?

Comment: If that's the case, you can use the UpdateView and change the post method. Inside it get the comments using the pk/id parameter and delete them after or before saving the Profile/User.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need, how can I do this? How can I create a form with only input type submit?

Comment: This is a link to my code, the only thing there is no comment model, but it is the default https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64099930/dont-put-the-current-value-in-the-form